# How to interpret the $u',v'$ graph in the Krukal coordinates? how to find the light cone?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes

When dealing with Schwarzschild solutions to Einstein equations, we tend to go to the  Kruskal coordinates, where $R_s=2M$ is no longer a singularity. The Metric will then be written as:
\begin{equation}
ds^2=-\frac{32M^3}{r}e^{-r/2M}du'dv' + r^2d\Omega^2
\end{equation}
And the $u'$ $v'$ graphic will be as the following:
[image]

When we are in normal coordinates $(t,r)$, I find it easy to locate the light cone, future and past...

But in these new coordinates how can one deduce that for example, if you go through $R=2M$ then you will inevitably fall in the singularity $r=0$?

(That's just an example) My question in general is how can you read this graphic?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: Nop, I am reading different papers on Black hole thermodynamics, this particular graph came from these notes that I found on the internet : https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0502195.pdf I am attempting to construct a toy model for a black hole for my research project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kruskal $u'$ and $v'$ are lightcone coordinates, meaning that (radial) lightrays follow lines of constant $u'$ or constant $v'$ (depending on whether they are ingoing or outgoing). This makes it extremely easy to find lightcone in the Kruskal diagrams such as the one shown in the question (note that the diagram is drawn such that the  $u'$ and $v'$ axes are diagonals!): Lightcones are simply always diagonals in the diagram.

You can now immediately see that the future lightcone of any event inside the $r=2M$ line always ends on the $R=0$ future singularity. Similarly, one immediately sees that the horizon itself is a null surface.

Comment: Very clear, thanks :)